# How to best retrieve data from a complex view in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a complex model

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get; set;}
     public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string State{get; set;}
}
```

In my edit view I display the Address.State

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.State)
```

My post action method looks like

```
public ActionResult Edit(Person person)
{
    var state = person.Address.State;
    return view();
}
```

But the Addresses is `null`.

What is the right way to use a complex model like this?

Comment: What does `Contact` look like?

Comment: You are using Contact model, but shown here Person model!

Comment: I agree with @ssilas777

Comment: Sorry typos on my part. Been corrected in the example above. Been awake too long trying to get a handle on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here goes the solution -

I used your model -

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Then the Controller action which renders the Edit view is as follows -

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.Name = "Rami";
        p.Address = new Address();
        p.Address.State = "California";
        return View(p);
    }
```

And the Edit view is as follows -

```
@model MVC.Controllers.Person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit","Person",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address.State, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.State)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.State)

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Finally when you click on the Submit button, it will hit following controller action -

```
    public ActionResult Submit(Person p)
    {
        // Do something with Person p
        return null;
    }
```

And when you put a breakpoint you will get new values as shown like below -

[image]